# JavaScript (TypeScript/Angular): Shortest/Fastest method to set object keys/values based on previous logic?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm attempting to fill an array with objects where the objects are all the same, and the keys are determined from a predefined item. I know I can do this with multiple if...else, but that seems to be a long method to use and was hoping for something more condensed and/or efficient without using external libraries.

Current method to fill array with hardcoded Objects:

```
fillArray(arr,n) {
  while(arr.length < n) {
    arr.push({
        'x': Math.round(Math.random(),
        'name': 'item' + arr.length + 1
    });
  }
}
```

Example of what I'd like to achieve using an if:

```
fillArray(arr, n, type) {
  while(arr.length < n) {
    if ( type === 'type1' ) {
      arr.push({
        'x': Math.round(Math.random(),
        'name': 'item' + arr.length + 1
      });
    } else if ( type === 'type2') {
      arr.push({
        'x': Math.round(Math.random(),
        'y': Math.round(Math.random(),
        'name': 'item' + arr.length + 1
      });
    }
  }
}
```

In my application I will use this type of method with a dozen if items, and there will be similar methods as well. I do *not* wish to apply any static typing for these items, since my application may require object keys to be dynamically added.

An idea I had that I can't seem to get a complete idea in my head would be somehow pre-defining an array of objects, and then using a find to somehow apply each item in the array as a type.

Psuedo-code (untested):

```
myTypes = [{
  type: 'type1', keys: ['x', 'name']},
  {type: 'type2', keys: ['x', 'y', 'name']
}];
fillArray(arr,n, type) {
  let currentType = this.myTypes.find( myTypes => myTypes.type === type).keys
  while(arr.length < n) {
    // add for loop to iterate over each key/value here separately
  }
}
```

Would this type of method work, be efficient, and is a reasonable practice to this approach? Are there any other standard practices for this type of array population with dynamic keys?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear, what is the pre-defined item that is determining the key? the `type` as flagged in your `if` statements?

Comment: I want the method to accept an argument, and populate based off that argument. I forgot to add the argument in `if` example, but updated. Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: I'm guessing you could provide an abstraction if you also made a mapping for the return values of `x`, `y`, `name` etc. like `[{name:function(loop){return 'item'+loop}}]`. then just loop over the type array and call the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving to dynamic properties with object like `keys` will harm type safety. Since TypeScript is a primary language, this is an important concern. Also, `keys` doesn't allow to control property values.

It can be a hierarchy of classes or some factory functions:

```
class Type1 {
  x = ...;
  name = ...;
}

class Type2 extends Type1 {
  y = ...;
}

const typesMap = { type1: Type1, type2: Type2 };

fillArray(arr, n, type) {
  while(arr.length < n) {
    arr.push(new typesMap[type])
  }
}
```

The difference from the original code is that it won't work properly if `type` is incorrect or missing, which may or may not be desirable.